# Javascript push() shorthand?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Is there a shorthand for JavaScript's (or even in coffeescript) `.push()`, when appending a value to an array? Much like php's `$array[] = 'added to array';`.

Comment: `Array.prototype.a = Array.prototype.push; var arr = []; arr.a('something');`; see, short :)

Comment: @Jack - Don't let me catch you using that in some real code!

Comment: There are no shortcuts, but there is probably a better way of writing whatever it is you're writing. You do not need to `push` elements into an array very often in idiomatic CoffeeScript.

Comment: `.push()` is *two* characters longer than `[] = ` if you count the spaces. Are people really *that* lazy?

Comment: @NullUserException Absolutely nothing wrong with [lazy programmers](http://threevirtues.com/), quite the opposite really... I'd happily shave off two characters from a common method invocation, but I would *never* choose to replace something readable like `push(...)` with PHP's fugly `[] =` :p

Comment: @meagar But this adds no efficiency or clarity to the code. It's like arguing we should always use one character variables because they are shorter. Arguably it's worse because I can't think of any other language that supports that construct; they all require `.push`, `.append` or something like that.

Comment: @NullUserException - Don't let Uncle Bob catch you with those variables!

Comment: @NullUserException Err, yes, you replied while I was clarifying my thoughts.

Comment: I agree with NullUserException. There's nothing wrong with `.push()`, it's the idiomatic way to append to an array in JavaScript. Learn JavaScript and use it the way it's intended. Don't try to make it behave like PHP; the last thing we need is another PHP.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Nope.

You'll just have to use `.push()`.

The use of coffeescript will only afford you the convenience of dropping the parentheses.

Comment: I don't always `.push()` data, but when I do, I prefer `.a()` =D +1

Comment: @Jack - I hope your address is not available anywhere on the internet! :P

Comment: @Jack, do you then use a post-processor to swap out instances of `.a()` for `.push()` before the code leaves your computer? If you don't - you should!

Comment: @BillyMoon A post-processor is too much effort; changing the prototype is much easier.

Comment: @Jack, how about just writing `.a)` and using a pre-processor to substitute it for `.a()` - that way you don't need to type so many characters.

Comment: @Jack 5 years later but why not use coffee script and just use .a ?

Answer (score 10):

You can use `arr[arr.length] = "new value"` but there's no other shortcut.

Comment: Do you seriously consider `arr[arr.length] = "new value"` to be a shortcut?

Comment: I just added another solution than push method. I shouldnt have call it a shortcut.

Comment: This is a fine solution that is easier to read sometimes when you don't want to have too many nested layer. Example: `arr[arr.length] = something.find(function(s) {...});` may be easier to read than `arr.push(something.find(function(s){...}))`. Personal preference

Comment: @Jake I would suggest `let found = something.find((s)=>{...}); arr.push(found);` is much more readable.

Comment: for what it's worth, it could be a short-cut (albeit a slight one) in some cases 'arr[i] = "new value"'.length // 20. 
'arr.push("new value")'.length // 21.

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly an `array.push()` but might come in handy in some situations and works somewhat like it.

```
const cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
var myNewArray =  [...cars, "Honda"];
```

This creates `["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "Honda"]` and assigns to `myNewArray` variable.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Are there disadvantages compared to `array.push()`?

Comment: not to my knowledge. :) This will give you more insight into this. Hope this helps. :). 
   https://dev.to/sagar/three-dots---in-javascript-26ci