# Javascript Auto Increment Array

Tags: javascript, php, auto-increment

Is there a shorthand way to auto increment a Javascript array like you can in PHP?

PHP Example:

```
$myArray=[];
$myArray[] = [ 'item1' , 'item2' ];
$myArray[] = [ 'item3' , 'item4' ];
```

JS Example:

```
let myArray = [];
myArray[ myArray.length ] = [ 'item1' , 'item2' ];
myArray[ myArray.length ] = [ 'item3' , 'item4 '];
//or
myArray.push( [ 'item1' , 'item2' ] );
myArray.push( [ 'item3' , 'item4' ] );
```

**Without** using myArray.length or myArray.push()

Comment: No, .push is the shortest/cleanest way to do that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript push() shorthand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18819384/javascript-push-shorthand)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the ES6 way, using spread operator

```
const arr1 = [1,2,3];
const arr2 = [3,4,5];
const arr3 = [...arr1, ...arr2]; // arr3 ==> [1,2,3,3,4,5]
```

OR

just by using the `concat` method

```
const arr1 = [1,2,3];
const arr2 = [3,4,5];
const arr3 = arr1.concat(arr2); // arr3 ==> [1,2,3,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Beside the given answers, you could use [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) with a great value for adding the values to the end of the array.

```js
var array = [];

array.splice(Infinity, 0, ...['item1', 'item2']);
array.splice(Infinity, 0, ...['item3', 'item4']);

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is certainly a way to do exactly the same thing; it even has similar construction:

```
let arr = ['a', 'b'];
arr = arr.concat([['c', 'd']]);//['a', 'b', ['c', 'd']]
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$arr = ["a", "b"];
$arr[] = ["c", "d"];
print_r($arr);
?>

Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
            [1] => d
        )
)
```

Comment: This would produce a different result compared to the OP's example, though. This would create a one dimensional array while the OP's example would create a multidimensional array.